# Invalid Source message on Background Video

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to put video on a website, and this is what I have on the HTML page.

```
<video id="bgVideo" controls preload="true" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="../pim flag.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    <source src="../pim flag.ogv" type="video/ogg" >    
    <source src="../pim flag.webm" type="video/webm" > 
</video>     
<script src="css/hstyle.css" type="text/hstyle.css"></script>
```

This is at CSS page
    body

```
{
background:  url("../pim flag.mp4") no-repeat fixed center;
}

video#bgVideo {
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -100;    
background-size: cover;
}
```

It only shows a small black box on the page that says: Invalid Source
Please anyone. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cant use blank space, replace this with a dash `-`in your CSS, src and the actual file  name on your server.

```
<video id="bgVideo" controls preload="true" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="../pim-flag.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    <source src="../pim-flag.ogv" type="video/ogg" >    
    <source src="../pim-flag.webm" type="video/webm" > 
</video>
```